# Is it possible to have different color in between a specific patterns?

Tags: auctex, faces

I am using `\begin{comment} hello world \end{comment}` in order to comment out text in AucTex mode.

In general I am using different color for comments but when I use `\begin{comment}` [text] `\end{comment}`, the text in between them shows up as white (normal text color). I want it to be seen as in original comment color.

[image]

```
(setq LaTeX-item-indent 0)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
(require 'tex)

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (TeX-global-PDF-mode t)
  ))
```

General question: Is it possible to have different color in between a specific pattern?

Narrowed question: How can I have different color in auxtex for text for all kind of comments such as in between `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be automatic if you have `\usepackage{comment}` or `\usepackage{verbatim}` in your preamble. At the time the question was asked, it was actually automatic only with `\usepackage{comment}`, but AUCTeX 12.3 onwards [will do it for `\usepackage{verbatim}` as well](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=cfb6b1fb5bf1d04aae82856ef30f73a83b9d1938).

If you've just added the `\usepackage` command, run [`TeX-normal-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Parsing-Files.html#index-TeX_002dnormal_002dmode) (`C-c C-n`) to tell AUCTeX to parse the preamble again.

More generally, if you define your own environments using a LaTeX package that AUCTeX doesn't know about, you can ask AUCTeX to parse the `.sty` file. See [automatic customization](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Automatic.html#Automatic). As a last resort, if your LaTeX code is too complex for AUCTeX to parse, [write your own style support](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Style-Files.html#Style-Files). You can look at [`style/comment.el`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/style/comment.el?h=release_12_2) in the AUCTeX distribution to see how the `{comment}` environment from the `comment.sty` package is declared: it adds an entries to `font-latex-syntactic-keywords-extra`, which is used to [override syntax information](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntactic-Font-Lock.html#Syntactic-Font-Lock) to declare `\begin{comment}` as having comment-start syntax and `\end{comment}` as having comment-end syntax.

Comment: I was using it through `verbatim` : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17822/127048 . `C-c C-n` says `Applying style hooks...done` and does nothing

Comment: Coloring does not also work for `\iffalse ... \fi`

Comment: Ah if there is no space or tav before`\begin{comment}` it works but if there is space or tab it does not

Comment: @alper Indeed AUCTeX's support code for the `verbatim` package doesn't color `comment` environments, only the support code for the `comment` package. This would be worth a feature request to AUCTeX. `\iffalse…\fi` is not a comment, it's a conditional construct, so there's no reason why it would be colored as a comment. Recognizing `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` only at the start of a line is also a design choice in AUCTeX because `\end{comment}` from `comment.sty` has to be at the start of a line, unlike `\end{comment}` from `verbatim.sty` which is implemented slightly differently.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - Fixed with [this change](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=cfb6b1fb5bf1d04aae82856ef30f73a83b9d1938).

Comment: @ArashEsbati Thank you!