# AUCTeX highlight contents of comment environment as a comment

Tags: auctex, faces, comment

I sometimes use `comment` environment in my LaTeX documents. Is there a way to make AUCTeX display contents of this environment as a comment?

Comment: Which LaTeX package do you use, `comment.sty`?

Comment: @ArashEsbati this one: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/58362/12242)?

Comment: No. I'll try it now